# Edittext, on submit need to show on another window in android

Tags: java, android, xml, adt

In android,i want to get a string from user using EditText and on click of submit button the string need to be show on another page/pane.

here is my fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"   
>
<EditText android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:hint="@string/entertheip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button1"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/thetext"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and corresponding java class is this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    Button bu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // to view the ip in another page
            try{
                EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
                String t = et.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(t);

            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });




}   

}
```

But i am getting the Edit Text and Button only, the text is not showing in another page. Kindly help in this.

Comment: What do you mean by "in another page"?

Comment: Where is the another page??

Answer (score 1):

place this inside onClick

```
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You will have to use an Intent to go to another activity, like

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, someClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

save the string in app preference and use the preference tag in that class and set the string to some textview you want there ...

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `onClick` to button: Fix that.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button1"
    android:onClick="onBtnClick"
/>
```

And you need not override onClick if you are not implementing `onClickListener` in activity.

```
public void onBtnClick(View v) {
    // to view the ip in another page
    try{
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
        String t = et.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(t);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //as you have kept visibility invisible in xml 

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try below way:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    Button bu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // to view the ip in another page
            try{
                String t = et.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(t);

            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from TextView tag of your XML File:-

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Comment: after removing that i got the text beneath of the submit button @PDWaghela

Comment: @TortoiseWalker Where do you want that Text View? If you will make that clear, May be I can then send you the entire XML code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate between activities using Intent and also pass data with it

[Using Intents to Create Flows](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Intents-to-Create-Flows)

Simple way on your case is

On Button click

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("username", "foobar"); 
startActivity(i); // brings up the second activity
```

On Another Activity

```
// ActivityTwo.java (subactivity) can access any extras passed in
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
}
```